# What does the "al" in "alarm", the default Arch Linux ARM processor username+password stand for?

Tags: arch-linux, users, password, terminology, defaults

ARM machines often have a default password. On Arch Linux, this is:

User: alarm

Password: alarm

I am assuming that the "arm"  part of "alarm" refers the architecture, but what does the "al" stand for?

Perhaps I am completely off on my assumption.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `al` part stands for Arch Linux, the `arm` part for ARM as you surmised.